# beautifulsoup find_all can't get div data

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I try to get html data from website,but data_table is return null
and try to trace the code,when I try to get header data it will return html context

```
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import html.parser
    from html.parser import HTMLParser
    import time
    from random import randint
    import sys
    from IPython.display import clear_output
    import pymysql

links = ['https://www.ptt.cc/bbs/Gossiping/index'+str(i+1)+'.html' for i in range(10)]
    data_links=[]

for link in links:
    res = requests.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text.encode("utf-8"),"html.parser")
    data_table = soup.findAll("div",{"id":"r-ent"})
    print(data_table)
```

Comment: can u paste the html structure from where you want to fetch the data. Also check the "res" value you are getting from the get request response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you visit the page in your browser you have to acknowledge that you are over 18 before you get to the actual content so that is the page you are getting, you need to so a post to `https://www.ptt.cc/ask/over18` with the data `yes=yes` and `from = "/bbs/Gossiping/index{the_number}.html"`, you can see the form if you print the source returned.

```
<form action="/ask/over18" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="from" value="/bbs/Gossiping/index1.html">
    <div class="over18-button-container">
        <button class="btn-big" type="submit" name="yes" value="yes">我同意，我已年滿十八歲<br><small>進入</small></button>
    </div>
    <div class="over18-button-container">
        <button class="btn-big" type="submit" name="no" value="no">未滿十八歲或不同意本條款<br><small>離開</small></button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Also there is no is *r-ent* on the page, there are only divs:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

links = ['https://www.ptt.cc/bbs/Gossiping/index{}.html' for i in range(1,11)]
data_links = []
data = {"yes":"yes"}
head = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0"}

for ind, link in enumerate(links, 1):
    with requests.Session() as s:
        data["from"] = "/bbs/Gossiping/index{}.html".format(ind)
        s.post("https://www.ptt.cc/ask/over18", data=data, headers=head)
        res = s.get(link, headers=head)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"html.parser")
        data_divs= soup.select("div.r-ent")
        print(data_divs)
```

The code above gets you all the divs with the class `r-ent`.

It is probably fine to just post once using a Session as the cookies will be stored so the following code should work fine.

```
links = ['https://www.ptt.cc/bbs/Gossiping/index{}.html' for i in range(1,11)]
data_links=[]
data = {"yes":"yes"}
head = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0"}
with requests.Session() as s:
    data["from"] = "/bbs/Gossiping/index1.html"
    s.post("https://www.ptt.cc/ask/over18", data=data, headers=head)
    for link in links:
        res = s.get(link, headers=head)
        BeautifulSoup(res.text,"html.parser")
        data_divs= soup.select("div.r-ent")
        print(data_divs)
```