# Python BeautifulSoup No tag and return empty

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have to get context like above but in html code isn't have tag to get data 
and I try to use get div.main-content to test but why data return empty?

```
import urllib
import urllib.request
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

links = ['https://www.ptt.cc/bbs/Gossiping/index'+str(i+1)+'.html' for i in range(15156)]

twice_link = []
data = {"yes":"yes"}
head = {"User-gent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0"}
for ind, link in enumerate(links, 0):
    with requests.Session() as s:
        data["from"] = "/bbs/Gossiping/index{}.html".format(ind)
        s.post("https://www.ptt.cc/ask/over18", data=data, headers=head)
        res = s.get(link, headers=head)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content,"html.parser")
        data_title = soup.select("div.title")
        data_date = soup.select("div.date")  #Date
        data_author =soup.select("div.author")  #Author
        data_times = soup.select("div.nrec")  #Count
    for x in range(1, 20):     
        url = data_title[x].find('a').get('href')[15:33] 
        data_link = ['https://www.ptt.cc/bbs/Gossiping/'+str(url)+'.html'] #訪問網址 這裡要二次訪問

        for ind, link2 in enumerate(data_link, 0):
            with requests.Session() as s:
                data["from"] = "/bbs/Gossiping/index{}.html".format(ind)
                s.post("https://www.ptt.cc/ask/over18", data=data, headers=head)
                res = s.get(link2, headers=head)
                soup2 = BeautifulSoup(res.content,"html.parser")
                body = soup2.find_all(text=True)
                twice_title = soup2.select("span.article-meta-value")
                twice_data1 = soup2.select_one("#main-content")
                print(twice_title[0].get_text())
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to get from https://www.ptt.cc/bbs/Gossiping/M.1119257927.A.60D.html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has an *id* main-content not a *class*

```
twice_data1 = soup2.select_one("#main-content")
```

Once you do that change, you will get your div.

You should also not be defining your functions repeatedly and as per the second part of my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38071989/2141635) to your previous question, you only need to post once to confirm your age:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re


def visible(element):
    if element.parent.name in ['style', 'script', '[document]', 'head', 'title', 'span']:
        return False
    elif re.match('<!--.*-->', str(element)):
        return False
    return True


data_link = ['https://www.ptt.cc/bbs/Gossiping/M.1119257927.A.60D.html' for i in range(1)]  # 訪問網址 這裡要二次訪問.
data = {"yes": "yes"}
head = {"User-gent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0"}

with requests.Session() as s:
    data["from"] = "/bbs/Gossiping/index1.html"
    s.post("https://www.ptt.cc/ask/over18", data=data, headers=head)
    for link in data_link:
        res = s.get(link, headers=head)
        soup2 = BeautifulSoup(res.content, "html.parser")
        body = soup2.find_all(text=True)
        twice_title = soup2.select("span.article-meta-value")
        print(twice_title)
        twice_data1 = soup2.select_one("#main-content")
        print(twice_data1)
```

I also presume in your actual code that you do something with *str.format* in the `data_link` list comp which creates multiple urls over a range > 1.

To get the specific text, you can get the last *span* with the *f6* class and find the following sibling text:

```
with requests.Session() as s:
    data["from"] = "/bbs/Gossiping/index1.html"
    s.post("https://www.ptt.cc/ask/over18", data=data, headers=head)
    for link in data_link:
        res = s.get(link, headers=head)
        soup2 = BeautifulSoup(res.content, "html.parser")
        body = soup2.find_all(text=True)
        twice_title = soup2.select("span.article-meta-value")
        twice_data1 = soup2.select_one("#main-content")
        print(twice_data1.find_all("span",class_="f6")[-1].find_next_sibling(text=True))
```

Which will give you the specific text. If you look at the source:

[image]

You can see the text is between the last *span.f6* and the next *span.f2*

Since the *f2* seems based on the second [link](https://www.ptt.cc/bbs/Gossiping/M.1467636128.A.23A.html) to be consistent, we ca use that instead:

```
twice_data1.find("span",class_="f2").find_previous_sibling(text=True)
```

Ok, as there is can be a newline before the f2, we can instead use `twice_data1.find_all(text=True, recursive=False)` to get the text from the div itself:

```
data_link = ['https://www.ptt.cc/bbs/Gossiping/M.1119257927.A.60D.html', "https://www.ptt.cc/bbs/Gossiping/M.1467636128.A.23A.html","https://www.ptt.cc/bbs/Gossiping/M.1467638164.A.524.html"]  # 訪問網址 這裡要二次訪問.
data = {"yes": "yes"}
head = {"User-gent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0"}
with requests.Session() as s:
    data["from"] = "/bbs/Gossiping/index1.html"
    s.post("https://www.ptt.cc/ask/over18", data=data, headers=head)
    for link in data_link:
        res = s.get(link, headers=head)
        soup2 = BeautifulSoup(res.content, "html.parser")
        body = soup2.find_all(text=True)
        twice_title = soup2.select("span.article-meta-value")
        twice_data1 = soup2.select_one("#main-content")
        print("".join(twice_data1.find_all(text=True, recursive=False)))
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay,I know what your comment.But I can't understand how to using function to get data what I want.I know I have to split all tags in soup2.select_one("#main-content")  (1   Gossiping    綜合 ◎記者，你的名字是抄襲。            HOTlinkinpork/to
2   Hate         心情 ◎幹!!期末考要加油啊                HOTloverlover/ci)

Comment: Go to https://www.ptt.cc/bbs/Gossiping/M.1119257927.A.60D.html and add the exact output you want to your question.

Comment: This is what I want.  我聽到的是：
記者問張跟路有沒有要結婚家人有沒有在催。。。巴拉巴拉的

Comment: Do you mean      `print(twice_data1.text)`?

Comment: Thanks, but not at all. I need text which color in white.Sorry I am a novice learning python by myself

Comment: Thanks @Padraic Cunningham. You are so kindly and give me a favor.But it's not everytime I can get twice_data1.find_all("span",class_="f6") so I have to add a condition to determent,or should I get data after soup2.select_one("#main-content") when "span", class_ ="f6" is false?

Comment: Is the white text not available always?

Comment: But If you try https://www.ptt.cc/bbs/Gossiping/M.1467636128.A.23A.html and it's different situation that I have to get data after main-container

Comment: Sorry I get another situation https://www.ptt.cc/bbs/Gossiping/M.1467638164.A.524.html

Comment: Yes! But it's not return anything

Comment: Thanks for your help.By the way do you have any recommend to study python. And I have other question for install python beautifulsoup in MacBook.

Comment: No worries, thre should be no issue installing bs4 on a macbook, all you need is to use pip. As far studying python goes it really depends on what you are interested in studying

Comment: Sorry bother you again. I try to twice_title[0].get_text() for loop get every url. But why sometimes get error:list index out of range. I post all the code what I edit.